# How to include all the files from JRE while bundling

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I'm using the javafx-maven-plugin for creating native installer. It all works fine. But inside runtime folder I would like to have all the files inside JRE. but now all the .exe file are missing. Can anyone please tell me how can I achieve this. 
following is the pom file I'm using.

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>8.8.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <vendor>mos</vendor>
                    <mainClass>com.smatt.morse.MorseCodeTranslator</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
</build>
```

and I'm calling mvn jfx:native cmd.
Thanks

Comment: did you check `target/jfx/native` folder ?

Comment: I did. inside native folder, a folder created named with MorseCodeTranslator-1.0-SNAPSHOT. There I can see the exe file. Inside this folder 2 more folders are there , one is app folder other is runtime.Inside runtime bin folder and lib folders are there , I assume these are copied from JRE. but can't see the exe files inside bin folder.

Comment: i now see which .exe files you mean... why do you need your JRE's tools? I think the plugin includes only minimum required (rightly so) rather than everything.